# No se muestran los elementos al recorrer con *ngFor

Tags: html, nodejs, angular

si imprimo por consola en el ngOnInit si me muestra los datos pero cuando los voy a imprimirlos en la vista no me los muestra

```
ngOnInit(): void {

this._productService.getProducts().subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log(response)
    if(response.products)
    {
      this.products = response.products;
    }else
    {

    }
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }

);
```

}

Mi html

```html
<h1>Todos los productos</h1>

<div class="center">
  <div  class="product-item" *ngFor="let product of products">
    <h2>{{product.nombre}}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

si miro la consola si que me trae la data
[image]

Comment: No, ya lo ajusté como me dices y tampoco. No entiendo si en la consola llegan correctamente...

Comment: Edita la publicación con lo que has cambiado, es como te han dicho arriba.

Answer (score 1):

Edita el If, dado que la variable se llama product no products.

```
if(response.product) { this.products = response.product; }
```

Si con eso aun no te funciona, agrega esta linea para que se detecten los cambios en la vista:

```
this.products = [...this.products]
```

Comment: Perfecto ! me funcionó con tu ayuda gracias